# Can not get email_Id of user using facebookSDK in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working on Xamarin Android Application.I am using **FacebooSdk** for facebook-login.My problem is I am not getting **email_Id** and **BirthDate** of User.
This is how I give the permission:

```
 LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(this,new List<string>{"public_profile","user_friends","email","user_birthday"});
```

This is how I fetch the email Id and BirthDate:

```
emailId  = e.mProfile.GetType ().GetProperty ("email").ToString ();
BirthDate = e.mProfile.GetType ().GetProperty ("user_birthday").ToString ();
```

Comment: I haven't used the xamarin SDK for Facebook but if it's like the native Android Facebook SDK user data isn't returned on login - you have to login, then retrieve the user details separately.

Comment: Can you try to get it from `GraphUser`

Comment: No,I don't know how to use it @RanjitPati

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xamarin's official facebook sdk. You can do this:

- When creating loginButton, set permissions to read email and public profile

  facebookLoginButton.SetReadPermissions("public_profile", "email");

Then simply use graphAPI to access name, ID, email and other public profile stuff.